# New to programming - Flutter SDK is not found in the specified location

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, flutter, sdk

I'm new to programming, I can't start new project with flutter because android studio showing this error.
what can I do ?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Android Studio **Setting** search for **Flutter** and provide path to your SDK.

[image]

Comment: I don't know if it's normal, but I can't find SDK's folder. it doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

to use flutter on your computer you need to download the sdk from  [flutter homepage](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install)
or you could clone the repo into your computer `git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git` if yo dont have git you can download git from [git webpage](https://git-scm.com/)

You will then need to export flutter  path.since you are onwindows you can do this by going to **This Pc =>**(right click) **Properties => ADvanced system settings -> Environment Variables ->** under user variables create **new variable** and set your path for flutter `flutter\bin`
Also install google usb drivers
Open android studio and go to plugins and install dart and flutter plugins,then restart IDE.